# Odd Nested List Behavior: Deep Copy v Shallow Copy Problem in Array Creation?

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, data-structures, nested-lists

I am using a nested list to represent a matrix. Most of the entries will be zero, but some of them will be updated with other values. When I go to update an individual cell, however, it updates the entire column with the value.

```
rows = [0] * 3
matrix = []
for i in range(3):
    matrix.append(rows)
matrix[0][0] = 1
print(matrix)
```

Output I get: `[[1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0]]`

Output I want: `[[1,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]`

What am I missing here? I think this has to do with some sort of deep copy vs shallow copy issue in the `matrix.append(rows)` call, but how can I fix it? How do I update just one cell at a time?

Comment: You're not using exactly the same syntax as the duplication question (since you don't use `*3` for the outer list), but you do build the same result by your loop that repeatedly appends the same thing to the matrix.

Comment: Try `matrix.append(list(row))` or `matrix.append([0]*3)` in the loop, and it will solve your issue.